# Session is getting empty when payment gateway posts response to .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, payment-gateway

I am Integrating the payment gateway 'First Cardinal Commerce' using c# asp.net(.Net framework 4.0). The payment gateway posts the response values to our merchant website. For that  created page called 'Success.aspx' which receive the some of response values from payment gateway which are posted by payment gateway after processing the transaction. I used below code for receiving the response values

```
request.form["responsecode"]
```

Here I am facing issue that, the session of the page 'Success.aspx' is getting empty when payment gateway posted response values to this page. I could receive the response values but it is redirected to login page due to the session is empty.

I am using .Net framework version 4.0

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how can retain the session when the page is redirected by payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your ASP.net session cookies are lost when you navigate to an external application and come back.

[Get Ready for New SameSite=None; Secure Cookie Settings](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure)

> With Chrome 80 in February, Chrome will treat cookies that have no
> declared SameSite value as SameSite=Lax cookies. Only cookies with the
> SameSite=None; Secure setting will be available for external access,
> provided they are being accessed from secure connections. The Chrome
> Platform Status trackers for SameSite=None and Secure will continue to
> be updated with the latest launch information.

First thing first you need to upgrade the .net framework from 4.0 to at least  4.7.2. or higher.

**Why?**
The updated standard is not backward compatible with the previous standard[...]Microsoft does not support .NET versions lower than 4.7.2 for writing the same-site cookie attribute.

[Work with SameSite cookies in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite)

[image]

**WorkAround for .NET version less than 4.7.2**

Modify the ASP.NET Session Cookie (Check if the Cookie Name is customized to a different one in your application). Probably in `Global.asax` `Application_BeginRequest` or depending on your code.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0 && Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie sessionCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
        sessionCookie.Path = "/; SameSite=None";
        sessionCookie.Secure = true;                
        Response.SetCookie(sessionCookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  For now, We have to keep the .net framework version 4.0 as it is, since we have some  other urgent requirement. Is there any other solutions for the .net framework version 4.0?

Comment: @Vijeeshkumarvofox Check if the Code in the post works for you.

Comment: Thank you Akshay, I have upgraded the .NET version to 4.7.2 and added the code that you mentioned on Global.asax Application_BeginRequest. It worked for me

Comment: @Vijeeshkumarvofox If you have upgraded the .NET framework you can use `sessionCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None` instead of  setting the  `sessionCookie.Path`. The solution provided was a workaround for less than 4.7.2